# Footer message information that next page have data in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

i know this can be achieved through formula.

please guide me how to archive this.. I am new to crystal report..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a formula like this.

```
if{table.column} = next ({table.column}) Then  " continues on next page"
```

Place it to the page footer section.